# Braintree iOS V4 Drop-In UI: How to skip the select payment method action sheet

Tags: braintree

I'm using the Braintree iOS V4 Drop-in UI during the sign-up process to create a subscription.

The drop in UI shows an action sheet to select the payment method and then a second screen to provide credit card information.

Is it possible to skip the payment method selection screen and take the user directly to the card details screen?

[Here's the screen that I'd like to skip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOp7w.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response from Braintree support:

> At this time, we do not offer any ways to skip the payment sheet and
>   go straight to the credit card form with the Drop-in UI integration.
>   With that in mind, you can build your own view to collect the credit
>   card information and tokenize it with the low-level tokenization API.
>   This approach allows you to design your checkout flow in any way you
>   want.

Comment: has this been changed on v3?